# Compound interest program

Tags: java

The question goes like this - Bank pays Manish interest every month.         Manish is also a determined investor and refrains from withdrawing anything from         this account because he now believes in power of compounding. Given investment         corpus, fixed annual rate of interest and maturity period calculate the amount         the Manish will end up saving at the end of his tenure. These are the         constraints given:

```
    P > 0 ; it can be float value, where p is investment corpus
    R >=0 ; it can be float value, where r is rate of interest per annum
    T >0 ; it can be integer only, where t is tenure(given in months)
    Calculation should be done upto 11-digit precision.
```

My code goes like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class CompoundInterest
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
float principal;
int months;
float rate;
double final_amount = 0;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Principal: \n");
principal = sc.nextFloat();
System.out.println("Months: \n");
months = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Interest rate: \n");
rate = sc.nextFloat();
for(int x = 1;x<=months;x++)
{
double amount = principal*Math.pow(1+rate,x);
final_amount = final_amount+amount;
}
System.out.println("final_amount"+final_amount);
}
}
```

If I give input as 25,4 and 6 respectively.. Output should be 152.
I am getting output as 172.Can anyone help me to correct my procedure of this and run this program?

Comment: is it your assignment?

Comment: Your formula doesnt looks correct. See [here](http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/financial/compound-interest-calculator.php)

Comment: You could ask your teacher how calculations with `float` values could possibly achieve 11 digit precision.

Comment: Assuming your currency units are dollars and cents, your balance is going to get rounded to the nearest cent after every month.  If you invest $25 at 4% per annum, you're going to earn $0.08 of interest every month, so after 6 months, you'll have $25.48.  The "compounding" effect doesn't even get you an extra cent.  Even though the formula tells you you should have $25.50, just try putting $25 in a bank and seeing what happens.

Answer (score 2):

With your program and your input I am getting 7000 as result.

Bear in mind that using 6 as rate the way you are using it actually means 600%.

Also you have to consider. Is the rate monthly or yearly? Depending on the answer you may need to divide it by 12. Hint : read second line of your problem.

Also. Where do you get that the answer is 152 from?
Without doing any math it is quite obvious that 25 dollars at a 6% anual interest rate are never going to turn int 152 dollars in four months.